# source code does not appear after setting up remote debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, pdb-files

I am trying to land my ASP.NET site onto the server. My code runs locally without any bugs, but there are bugs when I try to run it from the server.

So I installed and set up Visual Studio's remote debugger. It is running on the server as a service without any problem. I fire up my web browser locally and the site loads from the remote server without a problem (the bug is I/O related and does not surface until I tell the website to do the I/O.) At this time, w3wp.exe is a process that is running on the server.

I attach VS to the remote process w3wp.exe. The output shows that all of the .dlls get processed successfully, but the server's C# source code that I want to debug doesn't appear. I have verified that my PDB file exists in the bin directory on both computers and "Just My Code" in the debugger options has been disabled. What do I do to get the source code to show, so I can debug it?

Comment: Are you sure that all of the files in the /bin folder match yours?  Have you tried a "rebuild all" and redeploy, retry?

Comment: Are you getting any meesages like cannot find C:\blahblah\codefile.cs? or is it nothing even being presented to you?

Answer (score 2):

After you attach w3wp.exe to debugger,

1. click Ctrl+D, M to open the Modules screen (you can also open the same from the menu - debug -> windows -> modules)
2. locate your assembly, right click and select Load from -> symbol path
3. locate and select your symbol file

make sure that Symbol Status changes for that file to "Symbols Loaded"